# Fatal Error in exporting the moodle database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I was trying to export the database from phpmyadmin and this error is showing up

```
"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Export::getFilenameAndMimetype() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php on line 380 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php:270 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php(380): PhpMyAdmin\Export->getFilenameAndMimetype('database', '', Object(PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportSql), '', NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php on line 270"
```

And i tried to remove the cookies of phpmyadmin from the browser but this is not helping.
This is only happening in moodle database other databases exporting fine.
So how can i resolve this.

Answer (score 9):

In php.ini, first remove comma to uncomment and increase value of `max_input_vars`. Default value would be 1000 increase it

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 possible ways to do that.

**1) By using command line**

1. Open up a command prompt: Start -> Run -> cmd
2. `cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin`
3. Enter the following command in terminal

   ```
    mysqldump -u root -p databasename > c:\xampp\newdbname-backup.sql
   ```

   Or

   ```
    mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql
   ```
4. Paste the password when prompted

**2)**   **Or use phpmyadmin (usually installed with XAMP), or something like that and export it from browser**

*I would recommend you to go with first option.*