# Can't export database in phpmyadmin(xampp) : Uncaught TypeError

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

When I tried to export the following error showed

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to PhpMyAdmin\Export::getFilenameAndMimetype() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php on line 387 and defined in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php:270 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\export.php(387): PhpMyAdmin\Export->getFilenameAndMimetype('database', '', Object(PhpMyAdmin\Plugins\Export\ExportSql), '', NULL) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Export.php on line 270
```

Comment: can you explain more about your phpadmin configs or so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal Error in exporting the moodle database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369890/fatal-error-in-exporting-the-moodle-database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uncomment `max_input_vars` in php.ini file and change value from 1000 to a greater value

Answer (score 0):

it's works for me

```
$compression = isset($_REQUEST['compression'])? $_REQUEST['compression']:'gzip';
```

you can try it